# GCC compiler cannot find stdio.h

Tags: c, mingw-w64

OS - Windows.
I'm using a MinGW compiler. When trying to compile a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```

through the console command:

```
gcc.exe -g (filedir) -o (filedir.obj)
```

an error message comes up, saying "*no include path in which to find stdio.h*".

How do I make the compiler find the header and compile the program?

Comment: I tried re-installing `gcc` from the same website, but the problem did not go away. Perhaps I should try finding some other version of it? Also, VSCode seems to build the file without any errors through [the task](https://i.imgur.com/oFnblKT.png) I copypasted from somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. My problem was that I had two C compilers installed at the same time, the other one came along with Free Pascal. Found it out through checking every folder in my `Path` environment variable. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-I` option to specify additional include paths as part of the `gcc` command:

```
gcc -I /include/file/directory ...
```

Having said that, you should *not* need to specify an additional include path to find `stdio.h` (or any other standard library header). Review how you installed MinGW and make sure you followed all the instructions correctly; you may need to uninstall and re-install.