# couldn't run C in VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI4IQ.png)

> No include path in which to find stdio.h

Comment: i have installed extension for C such as Code runner, c/c++ extension and i have installed minGW also. But this happen

Comment: Have you tried restarting VSCode?

Comment: yes i tried, but its not working

Comment: Aside: Array indexing in C is zero-based. So the for loops should start from `0` and end at `n-1`.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or text. Post text as text. It looks like your compiler wasn't installed properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCC compiler cannot find stdio.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659198/gcc-compiler-cannot-find-stdio-h)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set compiler path in environment variables .

You can find your answer on this official site

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Comment: OP is receiving an error message from the compiler, so the compiler was found.